# Как правильно написать название организации?

Tags: склонение

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать в шапке письма, где хочу указать адресата. 
ВсемирнОЙ ОрганизацИИ Здравоохранения или ВсемирнАЯ ОрганизацИЯ здравоохранения. 
Шеф утверждает что названия организаций не склоняются, а я думаю что только те, что в кавычках не склоняются.

Заранее Вам благодарна

Answer (score 1):

"Всемирная организация здравоохранения" (второе и третье слова - со строчной) сама себя в шапке обозначит в именительном падеже. (Кавычки здесь оформляют цитату, в Вашем обращении они не нужны.)

Адресант же пишет - *кому*. "Всемирн**ой** организаци**и** здравоохранения..."

Вспомните, как начинают любое заявление...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ваш шеф прав.

Если адресат - директор или определённая личность, то да, кому - в дат. пад.с указанием должности, но если письмо будет направляться без конкретного адресата в организацию, то указывают  название организации в именительном падеже:
ОАО «Мистик Про»

В Вашем случае: Всемирная организация здравоохранения

http://thebestsecretary.ru/?p=1244